# How to setup python3 as cgi on mac running apache2

Tags: python-3.x, macos, apache2

I setup apache2 on a mac (big sur), and it works for an html page.  But I installed python3 on the machine, yet if I try to load a .py file in the home directory my web browser the system treats it like I'm running a local program and opens it in an editor.

I can't find any doc on how to get python3 to run as cgi in the apache server.  Any help?

UPDATE:  I added to the httpd.conf file:

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .py
```

Now it spits back the file as just plain text, even though it ends in ".py" but still won't execute.

UPDATE:  I removed the # from the load cgi lines.  Now it responds "Forbidden: you do not have permission to access this resource".  The file is 755, and all other files in the home directory are accessible.

Answer (score 0):

I had to put

```
<Directory "/...the directory/">
Options +ExecCGI
</Directory>
```

At the bottom of the httpd.conf file.  Then I had further problems with a "malformed header".  I checked the error log and it was seeing the actual content of the python script, so it must have been running the script.  I added

```
print("Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n")
```

as the first output in the program and that fixed it.  The \r\n\r\n tells it that i am done with headers and onto the body.